# python script that exctracts some values from serial output

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I've written a little script that captures the output of serial connection. This is the output.

```
                 CHEMONORM AG

      ZURCHERST.  137  CH-8852  ALTENDORF

   TEL: +00 00 4517200 FAX: +00 00 45172200

                   WATCHDOG



       pH            REDOX       IN1    IN2

   ---------       ---------    -----  -----

      7.1 pH          797 mV     Off     On

 RAM - TEST:         OK

 PROM - TEST:        OK

 PROCESS - STATUS:   OK
```

Now I want to store the values of the `pH` and `REDOX (mV)` into two variables.

```
var1 = 7.1
var2 = 797
```

This is my python script.

```
#!/bin/env python
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
        baudrate = 2400,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout= None)


while True:
        line = ser.readline()
        print(line)
```

Comment: Ok, so what is the question? What have you tried besides logging the lines? How about inspecting the lines and parsing strings to numbers? An ultimate solution might involve regex

Comment: This is more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'mV' in line:
    line_split = line.replace(' ','').replace('pH', ',').replace('mV', ',').split(',')
    var_ph = float(line_split[0])
    var_redox = float(line_split[1])
```

Explanation:

Condition `'mV' in line` is enough to detect line with values.

first replace - remove whitespaces: `'7.1pH797mVOffOn'`

second and third replaces - units to commas: `'7.1,797,OffOn'`

split by commas to list: `['7.1', '797', 'OffOn']`

and then just first and second elements save as float.

Comment: Please add some meaningful explanation along with your code so that the original poster can better understand how your answer solves her/his problem.

Comment: OK, I add explanation.